# AngularJS $http.get passing variable as param key

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and trying to see if this is possible.  I have looked at a lot of `$http.get` questions online but can't find an answer to this.

I have an api call that has three different parameter key possibilities.

```
$http.get(url, {params : {$scope.searchBy : $scope.value}})
```

`$scope.searchBy` is marked as a syntax error. It has 3 possible values from a dropdown list.

I tried `var search = $scope.searchBy;` but when I use `{params : {search : $scope.value}}` the value is "search" and not $scope.searchBy.

Any suggestions how this can be done without if statements and separate api calls?

Thank you.

Comment: What call are you trying to achieve at the end ? url?searchBy=... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to do something like this as this is valid javascript syntax.

```
var paramValues = {};
paramValues[$scope.searchBy] = $scope.value;
return $http.get(url, {params: paramValues});
```

When you define an object using the syntax you have in your question the property/field name must be a known constant. If it is variable, which you want in this case, then you can create the object first and then set the value using the `obj[propertyName] = someValue;` notation.

Comment: @malka - glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

Use [property accessor bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation)
 to construct the desired params object:

```
var config = { params: {} };
config.params[$scope.searchBy] = $scope.value;

$http.get(url, config);
```